# Extra argument 'boolForKey' in call?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making certain things happen when the app launches. I put together this statement. It returns the error: **Extra argument 'boolForKey' in call**.

I am using Swift.

How is this fixed?

**CODE:**

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults(boolForKey: "hasLaunchedOnce") {
            //app has already launched before
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults(setBool: true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults(synchronize)
            //first time launch
        }
```

Comment: This is unrelated, but you have different capitalization on your "has launched" keys, which will cause this to not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this fixed?

It looks like that call should be:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasLaunchedOnce") {
```

That's because the Objective-C method name is `-boolForKey:`, not `-standardUserDefaults:boolForKey:`. When translating to Swift, you generally put the first part of the method name before the left parenthesis, with subsequent parts appearing inside the parens.